# Google play payment issues

Tags: google-play

The commodity price obtain by my app through Google Play skuDetail.getPrice() is "price":"$21.73","price_amount_micros":21730444,"price_currency_code":"SGD" ,but when I buy this product ,tht google play pop-up box shows $15.99. SomeOne cal tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert $21.73 SGD Singapore Dollars to US Dollars, it approximates $16 USD